# AutoSuggestBox.SelectedItem is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

For AutoSuggestBox Selected item is Enabled in _SuggestionChosen event, but in "getitemselected()" method selected item is not working, in WP8.1.

In XAML File:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="tblkpersonname" Width="380" Margin="0,-7,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SuggestionChosen="tblkpersonname_SuggestionChosen">
      <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                          Tag="{Binding PersonID}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
      </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

In Cs File:

```
private void tblkpersonname_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender,   AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
   {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Suggestion chosen : {0}", ((values)args.SelectedItem).Name);         
   }

public void getitemselected()
    {
     //Error in this line when select item from AutoSuggestBox
     //Here values is the one of the class
      if (((values)tblkpersonname.SelectedItem) != null)
       {
          //Some Statements
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? I don't see where you subscribe to *SuggestionChosen* event in your *AutoSuggestBox*.

Comment: Sorry.. see the question now

Comment: What does "not working" entail?

Comment: tblkpersonname.SelectedItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoSuggestBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has no property *SelectedItem* - you can read *Text* property if you want.

However if you want to know which element has been selected from suggestions you can read it from arguments in event *SuggestionChosen*, what you are already doing. You just need to pass it to your method. For example like this:

```
private void tblkpersonname_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Suggestion chosen : {0}", ((values)args.SelectedItem).Name);
    getitemselected(args.SelectedItem as values);
}

public void getitemselected(values selectedItem)
{
    if ((selectedItem) != null)
    {
        //Some Statements
    }
}
```

EDIT - after OP's edit and comments

You can also save selected item in variable:

```
values selectedItem = null;

private void tblkpersonname_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Suggestion chosen : {0}", ((values)args.SelectedItem).Name);
    selectedItem = args.SelectedItem as values;
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But what about the class values in if Condition if (((values)tblkpersonname.SelectedItem) != null)

Comment: @DeviPrasad What class values? You are passing selected item as your class (`values` as I suspect). Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience one see the question again. In that we are not calling the "getitemselected()" method inside the "tblkpersonname_SuggestionChosen" Event

Comment: getitemselected() is a separate method it is not Referenced any were.

Comment: @DeviPrasad Then you can probably save your item in variable.

Comment: selectedItem getting null Value

Comment: @DeviPrasad Of course it can get a *null* value - you have to handle it, also remember that when using *as*, the result can be also *null* if the type doesn't match.

Comment: your code is working but in selectedItem getting null value, when i select a value from AutoSuggestBox

Comment: @DeviPrasad When selectedItem has null value? Have you debuged and checked what kind of object args.SelectedItem returns? Can you share a sample which will show your problem more clearly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74691/discussion-between-devi-prasad-and-romasz).

Comment: @DeviPrasad I still don't get where you have a problem - [please check this sample](http://1drv.ms/1IrEZ9a). Can you provide a sample with a problem?

Comment: That's Brilliant answer, Thanks for you Answer